# Align button value vertically in the middle

Tags: css, button, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a button with a value set to "*".

```
<button class="testButton" value="*">*</button>
```

I need to align its value vertically in the middle.

I have tried the following, but not working:

```
.testButton {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center; 
}
```

The padding is working, but I think it's not the best practice.

I have already reviewed other questions, with no clue.

Comment: Could you provide the HTML as well?

Comment: @Azametzin, just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is centered. The problem come from the character asterisk. Use something else than "*". For example you will have the same problem with "∗".

```css
button {
  font: monospace;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">*</button>
<button type="button">∗</button>
<button type="button">★</button>
```